# Brother scanner not recognized after Ubuntu dist-upgrade => 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, scanner, brother

Just posting here in case someone may have the same issue ;)

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, my `brother DCP-195-C` scanner could not be found anymore by `simple-scan`.

The message was :

```
No scanners available. Please connect a scanner.
```

Tryied every (few) solutions google had in stock<sup>[1]</sup>... Nothing worked.

<sup>[1]</sup>: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2029686 (sorry guys, it's a *french* forum).

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you, please, add details about the scanner model you are referring to and a brief summary of what solutions you've tried? In its current form the question is not specific enough for others to provide help effectively. Thanks.

Comment: @Mario thanks for the welcome message! Actually the purpose was to post BOTH question & answer ;) But you're right, I forgot to specify the model...

Comment: My pleasure, and it looks all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the problem:

1. Reconfigure package
   (seen so many posts advising to `uninstall`/`reinstall` the driver so I came to an acceptable *- though IMHO better -* equivalent solution):

```
dpkg-reconfigure brscan3
```

2. Launch the `skanlite` binary (which is bundled by default in the Kubuntu distro): **<sup>[1]</sup>**

```
skanlite
```

***[1]** Not sure that this step really helped, any feedbacks about this would be very welcome :)*

3. That's it, my brother scan was detected !